# Response.Write script alert boxes not working properly in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, response.write

I am in the process of creating an asp.net web application in C# using Visual Studio.

In an old post I was asking about popup message boxes in asp.net and was told webforms don't have them. I was given a quick fix by using: Response.Write("alert('Hello world');");. This works well enough when using it just once as a login confirmation upon opening a new page. The problem I am having is that I have a bunch of if statements within a button click event and only the first script alert works (if (poundRadBtn.Checked)). Would someone be able to explain to me why the other three don't work and if there is a fix or an alternative? Thanks in advance!

```
protected void submitPayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (poundRadBtn.Checked)
            if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
            }
        else if (usdolRadBtn.Checked)
            if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
            }
        else if (ozdolRadBtn.Checked)
            if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
            }
        else if (ozdolRadBtn.Checked)
            if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
            }
    }
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any difference between the first and others. Have you debugged to make sure that the other `Response.Write` lines are actually being hit?

Comment: The other response.writes aren't being hit. I tested by adding labels and trying to set text. I just don't get it, the code is copy and pasted for each radio button so if one works, why don't they all?

Comment: If the other response.writes aren't b3eing hit then the problem must be with the `if` lines. Have you stepped through each line while debugging and checked the values while debugging in your if lines?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will read your else if statements as nested.  It would look like this:

```
            if (poundRadBtn.Checked)
                if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                }
                else if (usdolRadBtn.Checked)
                    if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                    }
                    else if (ozdolRadBtn.Checked)
                        if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                        }
                        else if (ozdolRadBtn.Checked)
                            if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                            {
                                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                            }
```

That's why if the first if fails no other if statements are caught.

Rewriting it with empty else statements is one way to fix this:

```
                if (poundRadBtn.Checked)
                if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" ||
                    cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" ||
                    billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" ||
                    billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                }
                else
                { }
            else if (usdolRadBtn.Checked)
                    if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" || cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" || billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" || billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                    }
                else { }
            else if (ozdolRadBtn.Checked)
                if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" ||
                    cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" ||
                    billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" ||
                    billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                }
                else
                { }
            else if (ozdolRadBtn.Checked)
                if (cardList.Text == "" || cardNameBox.Text == "" || cardBox1.Text == "" || cardBox2.Text == "" ||
                    cardBox3.Text == "" || cardBox4.Text == "" || expMonList.Text == "" || expYrList.Text == "" ||
                    billNameBox.Text == "" || billAdd1Box.Text == "" || billAdd2Box.Text == "" ||
                    billCtyBox.Text == "" || billPostBox.Text == "" || billCntryBox.Text == "")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                }
                else
                { }
            }
```